# google v3 info bubble position doesn't center

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infobubble

When page loaded info bubble position can't get center.
But when i click the marker info bubble is get true position.

so this issue causes readable problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/onurodemis/QxvPR/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this cases I am used to postpone opening the balloon. One possible way is to use javascript setTimeout like here:

http://jsfiddle.net/PuxT7/5/

Using jquery $(document).ready() for instance will probably give the same result.